# Not able to animate close button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have create a div which appears on a button press with animation.But when i'm trying to do that animation for closing it.Nothing is happening.It simple closes.

Here is the link to my fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/4o669azn/4/

Please help

Comment: For what you're wanting, your best off using JavaScript with css, you'll need to add the animation to the div when close is triggered. If using jQuery something like `$("close").on("click", function () { $('div').addClass('animationClass'); });` apologies if any typos, on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Change old:

```
span.onclick = function() {z
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal1.style.display='none';
}
```

To:

```
span.onclick = function() {
    $(".modal").slideUp("slow");
    $(".modal1").slideUp("slow");
}
```

Thus you need jQuery included.

Comment: For animation i have used css.I want to do it using css.For div to appear i have used animation using css

Comment: so you want a solution based on only CSS?

Comment: yes.I want that the way that div came in on clicking the close button it goes back the same path and for that o have written a code in css but for close button its not working

Comment: No,The way it came down,i want it to go back the same way.And for bringing it down i had used css animation

Answer (score 0):

Here are your **Pure HTML5 and CSS3 Interactive modals!** - **No Javascript!**

[JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vka5rq5n/1/)

The future of web design is just kickass with all these new things you can now do without JS!
 So this works by creating `input checkboxes` to work as toggles. Attach a `label` to them with the `for=` attribute. These will act as your `buttons` Then place your checkboxes anywhere you want in your code and give them CSS value of `display:none;`. This will hide them for good, the invaluable fact is that they will still function because you have the `label` tag attached to them that will act just as a `button` to check them. 
 You can now make CSS rules on the input checkbox pseudo class of `:checked` and chain different CSS selectors to them to act on any element ANYWHERE throughout the entire HTML document tree! This gives you the ability to create **AMAZING** and seemingly limitless UI experiences with zero JS!

For the close buttons on your modal, I turned them into a simple `form` with a `button` tag of `type="reset"` Then attached The original top `label` to one of the forms using form attribute so When you hit either of the 2 reset buttons, It sends them all back to "unchecked" status and thus - the transition reverses back to initial! And yes, got rid of the animations and used transitions instead. They were the trick to finalizing it! and getting the animation to easily revert back to initial on the checkbox toggles being unchecked again. Reduced code by 50% at least!

I will leave final styling details up to you.

```css
#myBtn {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#modal-toggle,
#modal1-toggle {
  display: none;
}

#modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal,
#modal1-toggle:checked ~ .modal1 {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
}

#modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal > .modal-content,
#modal1-toggle:checked ~ .modal1 > .modal-content1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: absolute;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  
  /* Location of the box */
  top: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 70%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}



.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0 16px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  height: 200px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.modal1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: absolute;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  
  /* Location of the box */
  top: 20%;
  left: 39em;
  width: 30%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 70%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content1 {
  position: relative;
  
  left: -650px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}






/* The Close Button */

.close1 {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  
  font-weight: bold;
}



.close1:hover,
.close1:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}



.modal-header1 {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}

.modal-body1 {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  height: 200px;
}

.modal-footer1 {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<label id='myBtn' for="modal-toggle">
  pressme
</label>
<input id="modal-toggle" form="close-out1" type="checkbox">
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <form id="close-out1">
        <button form="close-out1" type="reset" class="close">&times;</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <label for="modal1-toggle" class=" btn btn-default" id='myBtn1'>Priority</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<input id="modal1-toggle" form="close-out2" type="checkbox">
<div id="myModal1" class="modal1">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content1">
    <div class="modal-header1">
      <form id="close-out2">
        <button type="reset" form="close-out2">&times;</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body1">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer1">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```